# Таймер на php + MySql

Tags: php, mysql

подскажите как сделать таймер на PHP c использованием БД?

Мне самому алгоритм не совсем понятен, как это можно реализовать..
По нажатию на кнопку в БД записывается что-то, а при обновлении страницы таймер обновляется. Если на вопрос не можете ответить, подскажите в каком направлении копать)

Comment: если при обновлении страницы таймер обновляется, то зачем "что-то" записывать в БД ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Друг вот скрипт , посмотри видео - перепиши код https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MabjuyWrDI4

Comment: Пожалуйста, публикуйте ссылки в качестве дополнения к вашему ответу, а не вместо него. После изменения или удаления материалов по ссылке ваш ответ в нынешней редакции не будет иметь смысла.